# What are good ways to compare how "representative" a smaller sample is compared to a larger sample from which it was taken?

Tags: distributions, sampling, sample, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

So basically, we have a sample of known data taken from a larger sample of known data. Is there a good way to measure how "representative" that data is, especially in distributional terms, compared to the larger sample from which it was taken? I'm basically looking for a specific metric that compares their distributions, and I would theoretically add data from the larger sample into the smaller and the metric should say there is an improvement.

It seems like the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test is what I am looking for more-or-less.

The use case is if I want a small representative sample from a large store of data to shove in a model without hold-out testing to see how that model generalizes--yes that's bad but that's this specific use case. Because of this limitation, I have to know that the smaller sample I want to put in the model is representative of the larger dataset.

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer your question, here's a way for taking a "representative sample" in a regression setting: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~minyang/Big%20Data%20Discussion%20Group/Leveraging%20for%20big%20data%20regression.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I also just thought maybe the Chi-Square Test for Homogeneity  could be used for count data.